# Sind "gemeinsam", "zusammen" und "selbander" austauschbar?

Tags: grammar, adverb

> Wir gehen morgen zusammen in den Park, um zu picknicken.
>
> Wir gehen morgen gemeinsam in den Park, um zu picknicken.
>
> Wir gehen morgen selbander in den Park, um zu picknicken.

Kann man diese Adverbien so  verwenden? Gibt es irgendwelche Unterschiede in der Bedeutung?

Comment: Never heard of *selbander* as a native speaker. You should not use this.

Comment: Es kommt auf den Kontext an. Hier sind die fraglichen Wörter gleichbedeutend, aber "zusammen schlafen" und "gemeinsam schlafen" bedeuten nicht das gleiche.

Comment: @henning *zusammen* und *gemeinsam schlafen* has basically the same meaning, *miteinander schlafen* deviates, as it often/usually refers to intercourse.

Answer (score 4):

*Zusammen* and *gemeinsam* haben hier die gleiche Bedeutung ([Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zusammen)). *Selbander* habe ich noch nie gehört, doch ich habe es auch im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/selbander) gefunden. Es ist veraltet und bedeutet *zu zweit*. Es unterscheidet sich also in der Bedeutung von den beiden anderen Wörtern, die keine Zahlenangabe enthalten. Allerdings scheint es nach anderen Quellen auch die Bedeutung von *zusammen* zu haben (http://zwei.dwds.de/wb/selbander).

Answer (score 3):

Vergiss »selbander«. In den letzten 50 Jahren habe ich diese Wort kein einziges Mal gehört noch gelesen. Bevor ich deine Frage las, wusste ich nichts von der Existenz dieses Wortes. Falls es wirklich noch im Duden steht, sollte sich mal jemand in der Duden-Redaktion ein Herz fassen und das Wort aus der nächsten Ausgabe entfernen.

### Zusammen

»Etwas zusammen tun« bedeutet »etwas mit anderen Mitgliedern einer Gruppe tun«, »etwas gemeinschaftlich tun«.

»Lisa und Walter sind zusammen« bedeutet: Die beiden sind ein Liebespaar.

»Das macht zusammen zehn Euro fünfzig« bedeutet, dass die gekauften Waren in Summe diesen Rechnungsbetrag ergeben.

### Gemeinsam

»Etwas gemeinsam tun« bedeutet dasselbe wie »etwas zusammen tun« (siehe oben).

»Lisa und Walter haben gemeinsame Interessen«: Die beiden interessieren sich für dasselbe (aber die beiden müssen sich dafür nicht mal kennen). Ein Briefmarkensammler aus Peru und einer aus Moldavien, die nicht wissen, dass es den jeweils anderen überhaupt gibt, haben ein gemeinsames Interesse. (Nämlich die Briefmarken.)

### Miteinander

»Etwas miteinander tun« bedeutet dasselbe wie »etwas gemeinsam/zusammen tun« (siehe oben).

Es gibt aber eine berühmte Ausnahme:
»Lisa und Walter schlafen miteinander.« Das bedeutet, dass die beiden Sex miteinander haben. »Zusammen/gemeinsam schlafen« heißt nur, dass sie sich im selben Zimmer oder auch im selben Bett im Zustand des Schlafes befinden, wobei auch diese Formulierung die Deutung des Beischlafs nicht ganz ausschließt. Aber »miteinander schlafen« wird praktisch immer als Synonym für »kopulieren« gebraucht.

Comment: +1 schon allein für     "Vergiss »selbander«"

Comment: Ein Dudeneintrag, der das Wort als veraltet kennzeichnet, ist hilfreicher als kein Eintrag.